# Bitmap set not working (Firebase Storage)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to retrieve and set an image from Firebase Storage. I declared an ImageView which I'm using in a Navigation Drawer Activity. I don't know why its not displaying on top of the message 'Hello Tester' (where the green area is), please see the figure below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    .  .   .   .  .   .  . .

    final ImageView profilePicbtn = (ImageView)headerlayout.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://urlofmyfirebbasestorage").child("userProfileImgs");


    final long ONE = 90 * 90;

    storageRef.getBytes(ONE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            profilePicbtn.setImageBitmap(bit);
        }
    });
```

Image xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewProfile"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" />
```

In 'userProfileImgs' folder, I have only 1 image called image1.png which is (800x600 pixels). Why is not displaying the image from firebase in the drop-down menu?

Note: I can upload an image from Drawable folder to this ImageView and it works.

Comment: Can you please paste the error you are getting from Firebase?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, its just not showing to drop-down menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso Library to show images in ImageView. You just need to pass the url, uri or resource to Picasso with image view.

```
Picasso.with(this).load(/* url of image */).into(/*your imageview id*/);
```

Before use the picasso, you need to integrate picasso library to your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

If you want to read more about picasso, please do visit to [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: what about if I don't know the exact url of the image that I want? I want to retrieve an specific image, how can I do that?